# error loading shared libraries: libcgmanager.so.0: No such file or directory

Tags: 15.10, libraries

I was trying to install CasparCG on Ubuntu 15.10 and now it's throwing a library error!

```
bin/casparcg: error while loading shared libraries: libcgmanager.so.0:cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have searched the web but without any results.

Comment: Where did you find it for 15.10? on the website I can only find compatibility with 14.04... Anyway, with `apt-file search libcgmanager` one can see that it is in `libcgmanager0: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgmanager.so.0`, so by installing `libcgmanager0` you should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
apt-file search libcgmanager
```

one can see that it is in

```
libcgmanager0: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgmanager.so.0
```

so by installing `libcgmanager0` you should solve the problem. –